# Beamerposter and fonts with xelatex/fontspec

Tags: beamer, xetex, fontspec, beamerposter

Has anyone had success with using `beamerposter` and `xelatex`/`fontspec`?
I am able to use `fontspec` for normal documents, but when I try with `beamerposter` I keep getting warnings such as

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/pxss/bx/n` undefined
>   (Font)              using `EU1/pxss/m/n` instead on input line 58.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/pxss/m/sc` undefined
>   (Font)              using `EU1/pxss/m/n` instead on input line 8.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/pxss/bx/sc` undefined
>   (Font)              using `EU1/pxss/bx/n` instead on input line 8.

It appears this is due to the size of the poster - I am using the a0 size.
I can use the `beamer` themes, eg `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` but really would prefer to use a wider variety of fonts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. This is nothing to do with the poster size, so we need to see what you are actually doing.

Comment: Hi - I ended up switching to a different beamer template and the problem went away. I think it was a combination of font options that caused the problem.

Comment: Which template works?

Comment: I used http://robjhyndman.com/research/beamerthemeRJH.sty